# "The resource cannot be found" when printing the page

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

I have developed a MVC 4 application. 
There is a page which should be printed as it is. 
If the print popup where we have to select the printer is closed, the web page gives a 404 error. But when the page is refreshed, the page gets loaded with no issues.

What could be the reason for this? Thanks in advance.

Here's a part of the page (The full page is very long)

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

     <div>
            @{

                string d = ViewBag.trans[0].REC_NO;

            }
        </div>

         <form method="post" name="main" id="main">



                <table x:str border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 689px" id="table5" bgcolor="#F3F3F3">
                    <colgroup>
                        <col width="64" span="7" style="width:48pt">
                    </colgroup>
                    @if (ViewBag.status.ToString().Trim()   == "1" && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.lastDate) )
                    {
                       <tr>
                        <td align="center" height="17" style="height: 12.75pt; color: windowtext; font-size: 10.0pt; font-weight: 400; font-style: normal; text-decoration: none; font-family: Arial; text-align: general; vertical-align: bottom; white-space: nowrap; border: medium none; padding-left: 1px; padding-right: 1px; padding-top: 1px" width="676" colspan="7" align="left">
                        <p>
                        <font size="2" color="#FF0000" face="Trebuchet MS">Rejected 
                        Receipt</font></td>
                    </tr>

                    }
                    @if (ViewBag.status.ToString().Trim() == "1" && String.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.lastDate))
                    {
                        <tr>
                        <td height="17" style="height: 12.75pt; color: windowtext; font-size: 10.0pt; font-weight: 400; font-style: normal; text-decoration: none; font-family: Arial; text-align: general; vertical-align: bottom; white-space: nowrap; border: medium none; padding-left: 1px; padding-right: 1px; padding-top: 1px" width="676" colspan="7" align="left">
                        <p align="center">
                        <font size="2" color="#FF0000" face="Trebuchet MS">Deleted 
                        Receipt</font></td>
                    </tr>

                    }
                    @if (ViewBag.status.ToString().Trim() == "0" && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.lastDate))
                    {
                        <tr>
                        <td height="17" style="height: 12.75pt; color: windowtext; font-size: 10.0pt; font-weight: 400; font-style: normal; text-decoration: none; font-family: Arial; text-align: general; vertical-align: bottom; white-space: nowrap; border: medium none; padding-left: 1px; padding-right: 1px; padding-top: 1px" width="676" colspan="7" align="left">
                        <p align="center">
                        <font size="2" color="#FF0000" face="Trebuchet MS">Initial 
                        Receipt</font></td>
                    </tr>

                    }
                     @if (ViewBag.status.ToString().Trim() == "0" && String.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.lastDate))
                     {
                         <tr>
                        <td height="17" style="height: 12.75pt; color: windowtext; font-size: 10.0pt; font-weight: 400; font-style: normal; text-decoration: none; font-family: Arial; text-align: general; vertical-align: bottom; white-space: nowrap; border: medium none; padding-left: 1px; padding-right: 1px; padding-top: 1px" width="676" colspan="7" align="left">
                        <p align="center">
                        <font size="2" color="#FF0000" face="Trebuchet MS">Cashed 
                        Receipt (Completed)</font></td>
                    </tr>

                     }
        <tr>
                        <td height="17" style="height: 12.75pt; color: windowtext; font-size: 10.0pt; font-weight: 400; font-style: normal; text-decoration: none; font-family: Arial; text-align: general; vertical-align: bottom; white-space: nowrap; border: medium none; padding-left: 1px; padding-right: 1px; padding-top: 1px" width="676" colspan="7" align="left">
        <input type="submit" value="Print" name="B1" style="NonPrintable; color:#0000FF; font-size:8pt; font-family:Trebuchet MS"  onClick="PrintElem('main')" class="NonPrintable">                
        </td>
                    </tr></table>
```

The javascript function I used to print the area.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function PrintElem(elem)
    {
      var mywindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=400,width=600');


        mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>' + document.title  + '</title>');

        mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
      mywindow.document.write('<h1>' + document.title  + '</h1>');
        mywindow.document.write(document.getElementById(elem).innerHTML);
        mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

        mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
        mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10*/

        mywindow.print();
        mywindow.close();

        return true;

}</script>
```

Comment: Show us ur code

Comment: Is ur print function is in `a` tag?

Comment: I had used "submit" as the input type. Once I make it "Button" the issue got fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like this

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="window.print()">Print</a>
```

Web browsers allow you to execute JavaScript statements directly by entering JavaScript code into the browser's URL text field. All you need to do is place a `JavaScript:` before your code to inform the browser you wish to run JavaScript.